# Methods calling Design Pattern

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns

I am working on Code Review of an app.I am looking for a design pattern that remove the duplication of calling one method more than one time like

```
UpdateAddress(InstallType.word, name, age);
UpdateAddress(InstallType.excel, name, age);
UpdateAddress(InstallType.powerpoint, name, age);
```

So, in the above example UpdateAddress method call more than one time with different params. Is there any good way?

Comment: Are they called like that in one method? Or are they scattered throughout the application?

Comment: You are needing another invocation such as stated by Tim B. That's not a design pattern btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (InstallType t: InstallType.values) {
    UpdateAddress(t, name, age);
}
```

But really UpdateAddress should be called updateAddress.

If you are able to modify UpdateAddress then you could change the method to either be:

```
void updateAddress(Collection<InstallType> types, name, age)
```

or

```
void updateAddress(name, age, InstallType... types)
```